# Socket / InputStream Dropping Data

Tags: java

I have been attempting to set up a basic server using Java's ServerSocket, Socket, and InputStream. In reading the InputStream, the expected result was a repeating series of byte 0x0b and 10 bytes of associated data (0x0b-data-0x0b-data repeating). The issue is that a small amount of the bytes are entirely dropped somewhere within the Java application, leaving only 9 bytes of data in some packets (after checking with Wireshark, the bytes are present in the original packets, just not the output of the InputStream).

The context in which this is happening is during a sequence of around a hundred packets sent in quick succession in response to certain behavior. I believe this is simply because there are more bytes that have an opportunity to be dropped and not the speed at which it is recieved.

After some searching, I found the same issue at [Java Socket InputStream read missing bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29985870/java-socket-inputstream-read-missing-bytes), but that thread died with requests for further information (and hence no useful answers).

The entirety of the code causing this problem is below. The most important sections are the while true loop and the readData function (excluding the else if chain).

To clarify, the question is the cause of this weird behaviour.

```java
package com.kevycat.minerria;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Minerria {

    private static Socket client;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(7777);
        System.out.println("Listening");

        client = socket.accept();
        InputStream stream = client.getInputStream();

        System.out.println("Connected");

        byte[] extraData = new byte[0];
        while (true) {
            int available = stream.available();
            byte[] data = new byte[available + extraData.length];
            stream.read(data, extraData.length, available);

            if (extraData.length > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < extraData.length; i++) {
                    data[i] = extraData[i];
                }
            }

            if (data.length > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    System.out.print(data[i] + " ");
                }
                System.out.println(" ");
            }

            if (data.length > 0) {
                extraData = readData(data);
            }
        }

    }

    private static byte[] readData(byte[] data) throws IOException {

        if (data.length < 3) {
            return data;
        }

        int length = data[0] + data[1] * 256;
        int type = data[2];

        String payload = new String(Arrays.copyOfRange(data, 4, length));

        System.out.println(length + " " + type + " " + payload);

        if (type == 1) {
            client.getOutputStream().write(new byte[] { 5, 0, 3, 0, 0 });
        } else if (type == 4) {
            client.getOutputStream().write(data);
        } else if (type == 5) {
            client.getOutputStream().write(data);
        } else if (type == 68) {
            client.getOutputStream().write(data);
        } else if (type == 16) {
            client.getOutputStream().write(data);
        } else if (type == 42) {
            client.getOutputStream().write(data);
        } else if (type == 50) {
            client.getOutputStream().write(data);
        } else if (type == 6) {
            byte[] b = new byte[80];
            b[0] = 80;
            b[2] = 7;
            client.getOutputStream().write(b);
        } else if (type == 8) {
            client.getOutputStream().write(new byte[] { 11, 0, 9, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 'e', 'e', 'e' });
        }

        return data.length > length ? Arrays.copyOfRange(data, length, data.length - 1) : new byte[0];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int available = stream.available();`

Don't do this. `available()` does nothing useful. If you don't believe me, I shall quote the javadoc:

> Returns an estimate of the number of bytes that can be read (or skipped over) from this input stream without blocking by the next invocation of a method for this input stream.

'estimate'. That's programmer jargon. In plain english it translates as 'mostly useless'.

> `stream.read(data, extraData.length, available);`

There's your error. You can't ignore the returned value of a `read` call. Read the javadoc: That read call will guarantee:

1. It reads at least 1 byte, unless the stream is closed / ended (then it reads nothing, and returns -1).
2. It will never read more than `available`.
3. **But that is where it ends**. It is perfectly legimitate for this method to only read half of `available`.
4. The *ACTUAL* # of bytes read is returned, unless it read nothing (only possible if stream is closed), then it returns -1.

The reason it's so convoluted is to get it to you as fast as possible. If packet arrives on your network card with 6 bytes and you ask for 10, it'll give you 6.

Use `.readFully()` if you want to just read X bytes (such as, 10 bytes, in your protocol that sounds useful), and ask the stream to wait as long as is needed (specifically, return only until either the stream ends are all 10 bytes are read).

For your protocol, I see two easy options:

1. Wrap the stream into a `BufferedInputStream`, and invoke only `read()`, the no-args one. That is a much simpler call: It returns -1 if stream ends, and a byte otherwise, easy peasy. It'll wait as long as needed until there's either data, or the stream is closed.
2. Alternatively, use `.readFully`. If you know that the data arrives in exact chunks of 11 every time, that'll work just as well. Although, calling a 'short' read (11 bytes is *very* short) on a non-buffered stream can be rather inefficient. Depends on the underlying stream.

Door #1 is less messy. It definitely does not suffer from inefficiency due to asking for too few bytes at a time, and it's hard to mess up your code.